# javascript initial capital function error in browser

Tags: javascript, function, replace

i have following function to make the value of control Initial capital.

```
ctrl.value = ctrl.value.toLowerCase().replace( /\b[a-z]/g , function { 
                                              return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
                                              });
```

When i run this in browser i get the following error in console

**SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters**

whats wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing function { to function **()** {

Answer (score 4):

Your function definition is missing the `()` parenthesis.

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------- vv
ctrl.value = ctrl.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function() { 
   return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
});
```